# Problem with imported stylesheet in svg file after webpack processing

Tags: svg, webpack, stylesheet

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS, in order to configure svg to use styles defined in an external stylesheet, you can import them as follows:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    @import url(mystyles.css);
  </style>
  <rect .../>
</svg>
```

This works fine in Chrome when the files exist in their original format, whether served from a web server or read from the local filesystem, but after building with webpack the resulting app's svg elements have no styling, so clearly the stylesheet isn't getting found.

All of the searches I've done turn up lots of info on what is more or less the reverse operation - referencing svg files from within css (e.g., to specify an svg image as the background for an element).

Does anyone know of a webpack plugin and/or configuration specifically for this case?

Comment: you probably need to include your webpack, and some relevant css. Also is the css for the html working - if so it means the css is being found right?

Comment: generally if you are in development mode your webpack will inline the styles in your html when you build. Thus your example import won't work, in that case it would make more sense to have your svg in the document itself (if currently you have it in an external file)